# Name conflicting in Theano

Tags: python, attributeerror, theano

I am trying to import theano in a module, but I am getting a traceback:

```
File "/media/tarun/6A86CA8286CA4DEF/develop/pydy/pydy/codegen/code.py", line 16, in <module>
import theano
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
from theano.gof import \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/__init__.py", line 38, in <module>
from theano.gof.cc import \
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/cc.py", line 55, in <module>
StrParam(""))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 223, in AddConfigVar
  root=newroot, in_c_key=in_c_key)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/configparser.py", line 227, in AddConfigVar
configparam.fullname)
AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'gcc.cxxflags')
```

It seems that there is some name conflict in some config. Can anybody please point me to the same.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens because some module, probably `theano.gof`, is imported twice. Usually, this is because a first call to `import theano.gof` gets started, registering `'gcc.cxxflags'` in the configuration parser a first time, but then raises `ImportError`, which is catched and ignored.
Then, `import theano.gof` gets called again, tries to register the option again, which raises the exception you get.

Is there any traceback or error message before this one, or something that would give a hint of why the first import failed?

Comment: It was asked about 10 months ago, and although I have forgotten the case now, but I am pretty sure it was resolved. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @TarunGaba Please post an answer when you find a solution to one of your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error using when using the jupyter notebook. Restarting kernel solved the issue.