# Installing theano

Tags: python, installation, theano

I installed theano with `Spyder 2.3.8` on `Windows 7 64-bit` by running `pip install theano`. It worked well. But then, when I tried to run `import theano`, I got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "", line 1, in 
    import theano

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 55, in 
    from theano.compile import \

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 9, in 
    from theano.compile.function_module import *

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\function_module.py", line 18, in 
    import theano.compile.mode

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in 
    import theano.gof.vm

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 25, in 
    in_c_key=False)

  File "D:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\theano\configparser.py", line 231, in AddConfigVar
    configparam.fullname)

AttributeError: ('This name is already taken', 'profile')
```

What does that mean?

Comment: Here is a similar question which does not have an accepted answer, but gives a possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423173/name-conflicting-in-theano

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you are using Spyder?

On windows 7 x64, I would advise to either use Canopy from Enthought, which, if you are a student , you can get the complete package for free.

Or, i also used WinPython before, it worked fine.
Although you have to follow all steps, including :

**Installing Windows Software Development Kit version 7.1 or you can install the newest Visual Studio which comes with it and it comes with an option to install Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7**

**Installing TDM GCC**

***But be sure to check***

http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html

*You might wanna check if you missed any steps.*

I had problems with Anaconda and Theano before. So i gave up on using it.
However a friend had success with it and Theano as well.

Just be sure you have your environment and python setup installed properly prior to theano install.

Doing

```
where gcc
where gendef
where cl
where nvcc
```

***on the Command Prompt Might reveal something...***

Im not a **GCC** specialist, but according from the link from the user above, 
i read a friend saying its something related to GCC.
So, yes, i suggest you re-check as i said .

Edit the question with that info and i might be able to help more and so will others.

@CantFindName

[Name conflicting in Theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25423173/name-conflicting-in-theano)

Comment: Thanks for your input but the problem had nothing to do with Spyder. In fact, theano does not support Python 3.5. So, I just had to create a 2.7 environment and install theano on it. It worked.

Comment: Glad it did! Sometimes using different python env's might cause issues on some python packages. But glad that wasnt the issue! I hope i helped you someway.

Comment: @ScientistGirl why not using spyder ? For information Spyder is included in WinPython, which you recommend.

Comment: @J.Martinot-Lagarde Then its alright i guess. However winpython hasnt been updated for like 1 year?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, they are updating winpython again.