# Getting Theano Bleeding Edge version to work in Windows

Tags: python, git, pip, anaconda, theano

Originally I had the non bleeding edge version of Theano which works fine in Anaconda 2. But I need the bleeding edge version for openCL use. However after putting "pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git" into the command prompt (which successfully installs the bleeding edge version)  Theano no longer works. Doing "import theano" crashes python (anaconda).

The documentation is a little hard to understand and I'm not sure if it is for windows (10) which is what I am using. Is there something else I need to do to get the bleeding edge version to work?

Comment: I had no issue using the same install method as you did on Windows 10 with Anaconda Python 2.7. It may be a dependency that is needed but I can't offer a suggestion without the traceback error.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

However, i had bad luck using Anaconda and Theano. 
Actually, you have to do **Conda install theano** , im not sure you can use bleeding edge like that on anaconda.

---

I would advise you to check [Installing theano](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630020/installing-theano/37780769#37780769)